# <input type="date> onchange fires too much

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In Chrome at least, the `<input type="date>` `onchange` event fires on every keystroke that changes the date, which means if you are typing the year, for example, it will fire on every keystroke.

But, they aren't done changing the date yet! Seems like this is what `oninput` should be doing. I thought `onchange` was for the change as a whole. When I'm typing 0,1,1,5,1,9,8,7 (01/15/1987), that's not 8 changes, that's 1.

You could say, well, check the value `onblur`, but then my event will fire even if they are just tabbing through the field and it didn't change.

My handler is a generic ajax postback routine that doesn't / can't check the old vs new value.

Isn't there an event that fires only on a change (but when they are done changing)?

Maybe in `onblur` I could check the old value but I'm not sure how.

```html
<input type="date" onchange="alert('changed')">
```

Comment: You can throttle/debounce. Delay the logic check until the user stops typing for 1 second or so.

Comment: Firefox holds the `change` event until the user is done picking the date which seems much more sensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="date" id="mydate">
```

And Js:

```
let mydate=window.document.getElementById("mydate");
let olddate=mydate.value;
let isChanged = function(){
  if(mydate.value!== olddate){
    olddate=mydate.value;
    return true;
  };
  return false;
};
mydate.addEventListener("blur", function(){
  if(isChanged())
    alert("changed!");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use both handlers. Use the onChange to flag that the input has changed, and on the onBlur handler, check to see if it has been changed before doing whatever logic you need to do.

Comment: That's not very useful... I guess there is a better way to do it.

Comment: ok, I see you're kinda new to S/O. Do you know how to do code snippets yet? I have one in my question, for example. They are easy.

Comment: @xale94, I'm open to more ideas, but this looks like it will work. What did you have in mind?

Comment: @toddmo Of course it will work. It's not a bad answer, but I mean that there must be some way to do it without use two different triggers. Let me think about it...

Comment: @toddmo I've done an answer without two triggers, just a function to check previous value and a trigger. Maybe you prefer that method. It's true that there's no big change.

Comment: Here's +1 for the idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Easy debounce :

```js
let timeoutDebounce = null

function onInputChanged(){

    console.log("Keydown event")
    
    clearTimeout(timeoutDebounce)
    
    timeoutDebounce = setTimeout( () => {
        console.log("Checking the date!")
    }, 1000)
}
```

```html
<input onchange="onInputChanged()" type="date"/>
```

Comment: I got this done without polling, thanks. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

onblur requires the user to exit the input element (tab or click away).

Debounce doesn't help when the user pauses. For example, typing in 1980 but pausing after "19" will trigger with a year of 19 instead of waiting for 1980.

checkValidity() works if you have min/max or other constraints set.

```
<input type="date" min="1980-01-01" max="1989-12-31"
    onChange="if(this.checkValidity) console.log('I love the 80s')">
```

Ignores onChange unless the date is valid.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Easiest and most straightforward implementation.

Comment: I needed to add paens "()" to invoke validation, but otherwise, worked fine: this.checkValidity()

Comment: @GreatScott Except that lots of changes will still pass the Validity check without being final. It _reduces_ the number of times your code will execute but doesn't make it just once for any amount of input. My problem is that I have a `datetime-local` field and they may be changing any of 5 or 6 components — and I have to compare the value to other fields. At some intermediate points in entry it will definitely be invalid, even though it's a valid date/time. I think I need to use the blur event

Answer (score 1):

I have used loadash debounce function for this purpose that delays invoking the function until after wait milliseconds

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce

Answer (score 0):

ok here's what I did.

I took Peter's answer, and xale's code, and came up with this:

```
<script>
  var isDOBChanged = false;
</script>
```

and then did `onblur="if(isDOBChanged) doPostBack('Driver','DOB_Change')" onchange="isDOBChanged = true;"` on my `input`, like this:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" 
       data-val="true" 
       data-val-date="The field DOB must be a date." 
       data-val-required="The DOB field is required." 
       id="DOB" 
       max="2001-04-28" 
       min="1900-01-01" 
       name="DOB" 
       onblur="if(isDOBChanged) doPostBack('Driver','DOB_Change')" 
       onchange="isDOBChanged = true;" type="date" value="2000-07-18">
```

and it worked great